# How to solve MaxCounters - Coditility with Golang

Tags: algorithm, go

You are given an array of counters `N` initiated with zero.

You have a list of actions `A` to perform on `N` array.

each action is an int `x`

`ie A = [1,5,3]`

for each `k` in `A` as `x` actions

- if x <= len(N) then increase N[i-1] by one
- else set all `N` items with max of max value of `N`

you should return the counters array after the last action

[Exercise Link](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/4-counting_elements/max_counters/)

Answer (score -2):

### The first and simpler solution

- wont pass 100% because of time complexity
- create `counters` array with all 0 in size of `len(A)`
- for each `idx`,`action` in `A`
- if `action` <= `len(N)`

  - `counters[idx-1]++`
- else

  - `maxVal = max(counters)`
  - now set max maxVal to all `counters` items
- return `counters`
- small improvement, store `maxVal` variable in the top and update it with each increase of the counter items. Then when you need to set all items, you dont need to find `max` value.

### Better solution

that passes the tests 100%

We will still go through actions, and we store the max value and another new variable `forcedVal`. we will not update the whole counters array each time we need but only update the `forcedVal` with the max. Then when ever we need to `++` an item we will first check if it is smaller then `forcedVal` and if so we will give it `forcedVal` value before the `++`.

- create `counters` array with all 0 in size of `len(A)`
- create `max` var with 0
- create `forcedVal` var with 0
- for each `idx`,`action` in `A`
- if `action` <= `len(N)`

  - `cur = counters[idx-1]`
  - `if cur < forceVal ? cur = forceVal`
  - cur++
  - if cur > max
  - max = cur
  - counters[idx-1] = cur
- else

  - `forcedVal` = `max`
- here we do a single loop to set our counters
- for each cnt in counters

  - if cnt < forcedVal ? cnt = forcedVal
- return `counters`

this is how it will look with this example

`Solution(5, [3, 4, 4, 6, 1, 4, 4])`

```
| c[0] | c[1] | c[2] | c[3] | c[4] | action | max | forcedVal |
|------|------|------|------|------|--------|-----|-----------|
| 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    | null   | 0   | 0         |
| 0    | 0    | 1    | 0    | 0    | 3      | 1   | 0         |
| 0    | 0    | 1    | 1    | 0    | 4      | 1   | 0         |
| 0    | 0    | 1    | 2    | 0    | 4      | 2   | 0         |
| 0    | 0    | 1    | 2    | 0    | 6      | 2   | 2         |
| 3    | 0    | 1    | 2    | 0    | 1      | 3   | 2         |
| 3    | 0    | 1    | 3    | 0    | 4      | 3   | 2         |
| 3    | 0    | 1    | 4    | 0    | 4      | 4   | 2         |
```

as you can see above after all we have left with:

`3, 0, 1, 4, 0`

we will our final cleanup loop to set all items to at least the value of `forcedVal` and we get

`3, 2, 2, 4, 2`

```
func Solution(N int, A []int) []int {
    counters := make([]int, N)
    var max int
    var forcedVal int

    for _, v := range A {
        if v > N {
            forcedVal = max
        } else {
            cur := counters[v-1]
            if cur < forcedVal {
                cur = forcedVal
            }
            cur++
            if cur > max {
                max = cur
            }
            counters[v-1] = cur
        }
    }
    for i := range counters {
        if counters[i] < forcedVal {
            counters[i] = forcedVal
        }
    }
    return counters
}
```